# Mac: I/O Error when checking extended attributes files

Tags: macos, ssd, fsck

My Macbook Pro has stopped booting, so I went into single user mode, and did this:

```
fcsk_hfs -Re.
```

However, it always stops at this point (I tried like 30 times):

```
Checking catalogue file.
Checking multi-linked files.
Checking catalog hierarchy.
Checking extended attributes file.
disks0S2: I/O error.
The volume Macintosh HD could not be verified completely.
```

After a lot of researching, I'm now not 100% convinced this is a hardware issue (I'm using Crucial M4 256GB SSD.). Also because I had some weird Skype behavior right before system got frozen, and I did a reboot that never succeeded. I couldn't get around this problem on my own. Is there something I can do?
Also, what is this "extended attributes file" it checks? Maybe I can just delete it, so it would be rebuilt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions, in order

**1. Rule out File-System Errors**

Boot up off an OSX install disc (or connect your drive to another Mac). Use Disk Utility to do an extensive file system text and possibly (hopefully) correct file system issues.

**2. Attempt to make a backup image of your system, if you don't have one via Time Machine already**

Using Disk Utility still, you can make an image of your system. With this image file, provided the data in it is sane enough (depending on the problem you're having), you can restore the image on to another drive and have everything in your system as it was, just on a different drive. You can also restore a current system drive over on to a new drive, I believe.

**3. Check Hardware**

Your hardware vendor probably has tools you can use. Failing that, I'd get a Linux USB/CD Live version going and install "gsmartcontrol" (sudo apt-get install gsmartcontrol" (on Ubuntu). This is the tool I prefer for running SMART tests and whatnot.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @Doc. I've an Ubuntu laptop as my backup machine, and after installing gsmartcontrol, these results pop in "Attributes" tab of the disk:  
Raw Read Error Rate: pre-failure;   
Reallocated Sector Count: pre-failure;  
Grown Failing Block Count: pre-failure...  etc.  
  
When I tried to perform short or extended test, I got "Completed with read failure" almost immediately after start, 10% completed.  
Does this mean the disk is fried?

Comment: @brightnesslevels - Yup, so on Step #3, you've successfully identified your problem as a hardware fault. You can try to extract some data. I use the command "dd" to pull data. For ex, with my /dev/sdb being the bad drive, I may run "dd if=/dev/sdb of=/RawDataFromOldDrive.bytes" and try to get a feeling for where it dies. You could then run it again, but find flags to tell it to start after where the disk may be busted. Dump more bytes and then delete it call cause you don't know how to use them anyway. Hah, that's what I'd do. Maybe you can actually find a tool to help. Drive is dead though.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Doc. I actually didn't have that much non-backed-up data there, and those that I had, I was able to just plain copy, connecting the disk in question as a USB flash drive.

Comment: @brightnesslevels - Sounds like you're in fine shape. I'm sorry about your dead SSD. Maybe you can RMA it? That sucks. Cheers.